# If $X$ is a metric space and $T$ is the family of all open subsets of $X$, then $X\in T$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Using standard notation of balls, open spaces, etc., the statement reads

> If $X$ is a metric space and $T$ is the family of all open subsets of $X$, then $X\in T$.

Equivalently, we have to prove that a metric space $X$ is open. The proof given in my text says:

> Plainly, $a\in X$ implies $B_r(a)\subset X$ for all $r>0$ so $X\in T$.

Shouldn't say instead "$a\in X$ implies $B_r(a)\subset X$ for *some* $r>0$ so $X\in T$"? My issue
is that for example, if $X=[0,1]$ a subset of the reals and the metric is the usual absolute value function, then $B_2(a)=X$ for all $a\in X$. In this case $B_2(a)\not\subset X$ but instead $B_2(a)\subseteq X$.

Furthermore, a more understanble proof can be: For every $a\in X$,  $B_r(a)\subset X$ for some $r>0$. Thus $X$ is open and $X\in T$. Is this last statement correct?

Comment: I think the writer in your text wanted to be assertive but terse and ended up being confusing. I interpret the sentence "Plainly,..." as "Plainly, $a\in X$ implies $B_r(a)\subset X$ *not just for some but actually for all* $r>0$ so $X\in T$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to use $\subset$ for the relation you're denoting by $\subseteq$. (Besides, if you disallow the case $B_r(a) = X$, then the discrete metric
\begin{align*}
d(x, y) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x \not= y$}; \\
0 & \text{if $x = y$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
no longer gives a topology.)

As for the second part, the existence of such a $B_r(a)$ is the (or at least a) definition of openness in a metric space; you're basically saying that $X$ is open because it's open. The original version tells you why such a $B_r(x)$ exists: any $r > 0$ works. (Also, the conclusion should be that $X\in T$, not $X\subset T$.)

Comment: Ah yeah, true, made a typo at the very last sentence.

Comment: Ah good, you were right, I got confused with the notation.

Answer (score 1):

X is clearly the union of all open balls in X. As the arbitrary union of open sets is open, $X$ is open.